# Почему в коде с модулем pyglut языка Python скрипт не видит команды glutSolidTorus?

Tags: python, opengl, pyglut

Строю фигуры с помощью `OpenGL`, скачал модуль `pyglut`. Однако когда дело доходит до команды `glutSolidTorus`, получаю ошибку:

```
NullFunctionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-64fc35ca728e> in <module>
     40     glRotatef(torus_rotation, 1, 0, 0)
     41     glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
---> 42     glutSolidTorus(0.5, 1.5, 30, 30)
     43     glPopMatrix()
     44 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py in __call__(self, *args, **named)
    423                 raise error.NullFunctionError(
    424                     """Attempt to call an undefined function %s, check for bool(%s) before calling"""%(
--> 425                         self.__name__, self.__name__,
    426                     )
    427                 )

NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutSolidTorus, check for bool(glutSolidTorus) before calling
```

Что может быть причиной?
Я долго не мог загрузить модуль `pyglut` в силу проблем с кодировкой файла `setup.py`. Однако сделал это, принудительно указав при открытии файла `readme` кодировку `utf-8`.